# Даниэль/Даниель

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Даниэль.

> Даниель.

Comment: В заголовке слово _Даниель_ забыли с большой написать. Исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***Даниэль***.

1. Если написать ***Даниель***, то будет **другое** произношение, йотированный гласный  будет **ясно** слышаться.

Но в данном случае мы слышим нейотированный **звук Э**.

2. Это **проблемная зона** в орфографии.

**Буква Э** пишется после гласных для обозначения **нейотированного** звука Э (после гласных **по общим правилам** русской графики): *поэт, менуэт, силуэт, статуэтка, маэстро, каноэ.*

Однако и здесь **буква Е** стремится потеснить **букву Э,** а именно: буква Е пишется после гласного **при отсутствии звука Й** (произносится **«смягченный»** вариант звука Э): *проект, проекция, траектория, реестр*, в том числе **после И**: *аудиенция, реквием, иероглиф.*

Comment: _ДаниЕль Дефо_.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Даниэль  Для имени возможны варианты. Главное – понимать разницу.

Comment: То есть и так и так можно? Но в словаре Грамоты зафиксирован этот писатель (Даниель Дефо), и пишется его имя через Е.

Comment: Слово _Даниэль_ тоже там есть, но, в общем, и _Даниель_ можно, по словарю.

Comment: Как в паспорте написано, так и правильно :)))

Comment: У меня есть словарь Агеенко ""Собственные имена в русском языке", Москва, 2001 г. Там приведены варианты и указано, что Даниель – это женское имя. Есть еще Даниэль, Юлий.    Так откуда у Дефо женское имя?https://spadilo.ru/biography/daniel-defo/  В одном тексте пишут разные варианты имени.

Comment: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4098073-kak-zvuchit-imja-daniel-kak-pishetsja-imja-daniel-na-raznyh-jazykah-mira.html

Comment: https://dzen.ru/a/YRACC4xFlkJjTq74